# NancyFx per module or per route serialization

Tags: c#, rest, serialization, nancy

I use NancyFx, I've tried to find the answer prior to question.

I have a single return type per module, but in different URL routes I need to serialize it differently, just specific properties. 
If I wire serialization in Nancy pipeline, it touches all routes.

Is it possible to customize serialization per route or module without copy pasting the same type in different namespaces?

Comment: If i remember well you can use module or route pipeline instead of application level pipeline https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-before-and-after-module-hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with 2 solutions:

1. Derived type with `JsonConvert` attribute on corresponding overriden props;
2. Using serialization within module and return a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

Not certain what to specifically recommend without better understanding the requirements.

Consider implementing a response processor.

In your implementation of CanProcess you can examine the NancyContext to evaluate your rule for which serialization scheme to use.

Example:

```
public ProcessorMatch CanProcess(MediaRange requestedMediaRange, dynamic model, NancyContext context)
    {
        return context.Request.Path != "/" && 
            !context.Request.Path.StartsWith("/someroute/") && 
            !context.Request.Path.StartsWith("/someotherroute") &&
            !context.Request.Path.StartsWith("/login")
            ? new ProcessorMatch
            {
                ModelResult = MatchResult.DontCare,
                RequestedContentTypeResult = MatchResult.ExactMatch
            }
            : new ProcessorMatch
            {
                ModelResult = MatchResult.DontCare,
                RequestedContentTypeResult = MatchResult.NoMatch
            };
    }
```

See https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Content-Negotiation

Consider:  content negotiation using WithMediaRangeModel for the route.

> Enables you to define media type specific models that should be used
>   during negotiation. The negotiation pipeline will first attempt to
>   find a media type specific model to use and will fallback to the
>   default model, which is specified using WithModel, if it fails.